# Getting "504 gateway timeout" while calling external API from EC2 server as the response is talking 2-3 mins from external API hosted in Windows

Tags: python, nginx, flask, amazon-ec2

I have my vue Page and Python code API (uses flask) hosted in EC2 server. My vue page consumes data from the python service in EC2.
The python from EC2 further calls an external API (python code deployed in IIS) that is hosted in windows server.

My python code calls the external API as below

```
`@app.route('/api//callapi_abcd/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def callapi_abcd():
url = 'https://externalapi.com/api/callexternalAPI/'
timeout = 600000

response = requests.post(url, json = post_data, timeout=timeout, stream=True)`
```

The above response takes at least 1-2 mins to get the response, and I am getting "504 gateway timeout" resulting the failure in response.

I tried adding the below in nginx.conf and tried lot other options but no luck.

```
`"server{ 
   proxy_read_timeout 600s;
   proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
   proxy_send_timeout 600s;    
}"`
```

Need help if anyone have faced the similar issue.